# Oracle SQL - Is there a better way to concatenate multiple strings with a given delimiter?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

First question, so apologies in advance if this is stupid or unoriginal, but I've searched for about 30 mins now without finding any mention anywhere of my exact question:

Is there a way to concatenate a series of strings, to be separated by a given delimiter, without manually putting the delimiter between each column being concatenated?

To give a concrete example, I currently have this:

```
SELECT member_no as Member#,
(member_gname
|| ' '
|| member_fname) as Name,
(member_street
|| ' '
|| member_city
|| ' '
|| member_state
|| ' '
|| member_postcode) AS Address,
member_phone AS Phone,
TO_CHAR(member_joindate, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') as Joined
FROM MEMBER;
```

It works fine, and produces exactly the output I wanted, but as this is for study I'm less concerned about the output and more concerned with the readability and 'best practise' factors of the .sql file itself. I understand that CONCAT() only takes two arguments, so that won't work without nesting them (which is even uglier and less readable). I'm coming in totally naively here, but I was hoping there'd be some kind of magical AWESOMECONCAT() type of function that would take all the columns i need, as well as allowing me to specify what character I want separating them (in this case, a space). Any ideas?

Also, this is a separate question not worthy of posting by itself, but is there any way to select a column 'AS' and give it a name including whitespace? E.g 'Member #' would look better imo, and 'Join Date' would be clearer, but I've tried both brackets and single quotes after the AS and neither seems to fly with SQL developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can still write our own `AWESOMECONCAT()`. Unfortunately, Oracle has no in built function. As the concatenate operator does the basic thing.

Using double quotes in the alias, you can make the column references case sensitive and even accept blanks. But note that, any more references to that column/expression needs double quotes with same text.

```
SELECT member_no as "Member #",
(member_gname
|| ' '
|| member_fname) as Name,
(member_street
|| ' '
|| member_city
|| ' '
|| member_state
|| ' '
|| member_postcode) AS Address,
member_phone AS Phone,
TO_CHAR(member_joindate, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') as "Join Date"
FROM MEMBER;
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't try double quotes! Coming to SQL from Java/Lua the single quotes/double quotes thing is tripping me up constantly - don't get me started on how I feel about "||" meaning concatenate and not OR...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to concatenate a series of strings, to be separated by a given delimiter, without manually putting the delimiter between each column being concatenated?

The best way to do concatenation from 11g onwards is the new string literal technique `q'[]'`.

For example :

`select q'[This is a string, 'this is also a string'.]' from dual`

Comment: *q* operator is for concatenating?? The comma has misled you!!

Comment: Aah, you are right. Those are column names and not literals. it would anyway need concatenation operator `||`.